# Only one language in Polylang String Translation

Tags: wordpress, cookies, polylang

I need to translate some strings in Polylang / String Translation but ther is only one language in the table:
[image: only french]

I have two language created in polylang French and English:
[image: languages]

I should have a table like in the docs: https://polylang.pro/doc/strings-translations/

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

At the very top of the page in the admin menu (where the language flags are), you can select "Show all languages".